# How to disable 'shop by categories' block on left side of Magento products page

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

Last week I started a Magento eCommerce. After downloading and installing a Magento theme I was wondering how to disable the 'shop by categories' block on the left side of my products page?

Who can help me? I did a lot to find my answer but I can't find it anywhere.

Kind regards,
Dion

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by 2 methods.

1. Changing the Template page to 1 column, 2 column - right, etc or create your new page template.
2. [Preferred] Remove the block through layout handler in LOCAL.XML in your theme XML files.
   The layout handler for product page is  find the block name and use  (permanent - all over Magento) or  (temporary - in the page only) to get rid of the block.

Answer (score 0):

In your

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

comment out

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" 
after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
</block>
</reference>
```

This will remove that block.But overiding **catalog.xml** to your theme and making changes there is a good practice.Don't change the core files.

> Edit

If removing this doesn't work than your layout must have been overridden.One method is to enable the template path hint, and and in your layered navigation you can see the path for the template file that renders the filters list. In default it is

> frontend\base\default\template\catalog/layer/view.phtml

After getting this file name you can search for the file in your layout files. where it is assigned to the block.Search for this in my case

> catalog/layer/view.phtml

Yours may be different according to the override.When you get the block that is assigned with that particular template file than comment or remove it out and refresh.

Also check whether your cache is enabled or not.If enabled clear the case, reindex and check once again.

You can also remove that block from your local.xml file
just place below code in your local.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Are there any other options?

Comment: where you commented out the above mentioned code, is it in your base folder? If it doesnot work than your catalog.xml may have been overridden in your current theme.check whether this file lies in your theme folder.if yes than make a change there.

Comment: My theme only has a ajax.xml and local.xml file?

Comment: I have edited my answer.please follow that hope that may solve your issue.and first of all check the cache too.

Comment: No not yet. Tried everything. app/design/frontend/themename/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml does exist, but I've commented out that lines. No result.

Comment: I just removed another sidebar block at the same way. But if I do for shop by categories it doesn't work

Comment: If I enable Hints template-pad everywhere I see hints and block names except the block I want to remove..

Comment: Can you please help me?